# When to compose interoperable message: in app or Mirth?

Tags: java, hl7, mirth, medical

We're designing an architecture for communicating several applications and we have decided to use Mirth as (pseudo)ESB. In our processes we want to give back control to users as soon as we can, so when an action is fired by an user (for example, pressing Save button after filling in a form) some (necessary) changes are made in database and then a message has to be sent to another system. User doesnt have to wait until message is sent, so our applications gives back control when database changes are done. Message composition is done in background asynchronously. But we don´t really know which approach we should follow:

a) Start a new thread in our app where we collect all necessary data (starting from "primary data", this is, some primary keys that allow us to find all information) to fill an HL7 message and send it to queue where Mirth is listening.

b) Send "primary data" to Mirth and delegate HL7 message composition to it.Mirth can access directly to database to collect necessary data or another option could be invoking some REST/SOAP services of our own.

In case of option B, we have some doubts about how to invoke Mirth: 
b.1) Our app makes database modifications and writes primary data on a queue (distributed transaction).
b.2) Our app makes database modifications and call a SOAP or Rest service published by Mirth which all it does is writing message on a queue where Mirth is also reading (no distributed transaction in our app).

Some argue that composing message in our app and using Mirth only as a broker is "missusing" Mirth. On the other side, there is some mates that find accessing app database from Mirth is very intrusive and it should not know our schema. Last option, invoking an app service from Mirth which returns all necessary information for HL7 is like sending "primary data" from app to Mirth only to get it back when Mirth calls service (passing that data as a parameter).

Thank you for your advices.

Comment: This question would be an excellent addition to the [Healthcare IT area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65896/healthcare-it?referrer=zzSEh1b0idFc27gzFOBXTQ2)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if Mirth is the appropriate tool to use as an Enterprise Service Bus where your requirements include real time notifications/events to allow the user to proceed after submitting a form.

Without knowing more,  such as the architecture in play,  we can't really advise you.

IMO,  as one who experienced with Mirth integration,  as well as designing database dependent applications,  I would say that Mirth isn't the appropriate tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** There is not enough information for an "expert advice" and no single clear technically-justified answer

**(2)** Option (a) looks like least expensive and easiest to implement for the 1st version, especially with reuse of stable tested libraries like [HAPI](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/)

**(3)** In your design treat your [Enterprise service bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus) as a [black box component](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams.html) and concentrate on designing the interfaces and clarifying the [asynchronous message sequences](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/interaction-overview-diagrams.html). This way the service bus internals, the message routing and queuing decisions can be postponed to the [deployment time](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/deployment-diagrams-overview.html) with some coding effort and by following the [adapter design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

**(4)** Arguments worded like "missusing", "intrusive", "like it", "nice" perhaps indicate a valid point of view but as such do not create a measurable, verifiable decision criteria or performance indicators and should not be used alone

**(5)** This is the right time to apply a decision making process and weight-evaluate the various options. As a minimal formal input I'd recommend the [Plus/Minus/Interesting](http://www.mindtools.com/pages/article/newTED_05.htm)

**(6)** In your decision following points should not be ommited:

- securing data privacy (health state is a private property protected by law in some countries)
- fault tolerance (robustness, reliability, exception handling)
- maintenance costs (do you have qualified people to maintain it, can the solution monitor and auto-correct itself or someone will have to review millions of lines of logs manually)
- development costs (do you have qualified people already, how many lines of code can you reuse vs. how many will you have to create/debug)

**(7)** I'm sorry that my answer is not directly helpful, **my choice would be** to compose the message in a reliable secured [application server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server), whatever that means in this case and regardless of how it's [axons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axon) or [pseudopods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amoeba_(operating_system)) would be connected

---

**Last but not the least:** record the why you made the choice - forever, so that you can test and validate your assumptions any time later when the original decision makers get lost in the sands of time